# Reflection - Не удаётся получить указанный тип - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, типы, методы, рефлексия

У меня есть метод создания формы и пользовательского элемента управления:

```
public static void Add(Form it, string title, string type, string content, string mode)
{
    string fullname = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + "." + type;
    Type className = Type.GetType(fullname, false, true);
    var formObject = Activator.CreateInstance(className) as Form;

    string contentFullname = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ".Data.content." + content;
    Type contentName = Type.GetType(contentFullname, false, true);
    var contentObject = Activator.CreateInstance(contentName) as UserControl;

    if (formObject != null)
    {
        if (mode == "Show")
        {
            it.Hide();
            formObject.Text = title;
            formObject.Controls.Add(contentObject);
            formObject.Show();
        } 
        else if (mode == "Dialog")
        {
            formObject.Text = title;
            formObject.Controls.Add(contentObject);
            formObject.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Я инициализирую метод:

```
Function.Add(Controls.Owner.FindForm(), "Заголовок", "Form_default", "UserControl_main", "Show");
```

При отладки появляется ошибка:

> "Значение не может быть неопределенным.\r\nИмя параметра: type"

В строке:

```
var formObject = Activator.CreateInstance(className) as Form;
```

При отладки, нижеперечисленные переменные имеют значения null.

```
Type classname
var formObject
```

То есть GetType не может найти нужный мне тип. Но дело в том, что этот метод работал в другом проекте, хотя отличия в проектах нулевые.
P.S. ...Проект новый создал из-за сломанной БД и бесконечных ошибок из-за неё.
Так же нижепредставленный код подсвечивается с надписью: Представляет окно или диалоговое окно, которое составляет пользовательский интерфейс приложения. Используйте сопоставление шаблонов. IDE0019 - Сопоставление шаблонов

```
var formObject
```

Помогите решить проблему.

Comment: А какое значение у переменной `fullname`?

Comment: ExpressService(глобальный namespace).form_default(форма которую я указал в аргументе)

Comment: А может, в новом проекте `namespace` другой? Или форма находится во вложенном namespace?

Comment: Посмотрите точно, где находится ваша форма.

Comment: Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name Этим методом я получаю namespace, который в этом проекте. Если так рассуждать, он должен мне найти класс по этой строчке "ExpressService.Form_default" Форма находится в главной папке проекта

Comment: Ну, а если вы откроете файл, в котором написано `class Form_default : Form`, то какой сверху указан namespace?

Comment: Вы гений! Формы находились в главной папке, но почему то namespace был указан другой, с другими подпапками. Это наверно произошло из-за переноса форм. Ранее я их переносил. Я их пересоздал и ошибка пропала. Огромное спасибо за помощь. И приношу извинения за прошлый раз)

Comment: Пожалуйста! Ничего страшного, главное, что проблема решилась!

Comment: Написал ответ, вдруг кому пригодится в будущем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что классы наподобие `Form_default` находились в неправильном пространстве имён (из-за переноса из другого проекта). Из-за этого определение пространства имён через `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name` не работало.

Это приводило к тому, что тип не находился, и `className` равнялось `null`, что и было причиной дальнейших ошибок.